# REGEX to cleanup Multiline String with Multiple Spaces, Tabs, Empty Lines (PHP Preg_Replace)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

After parsing different websites with the php dom parser I'm getting multiline strings with a lot of empty lines, unexpected carriage returns, multiple spaces, tabs and other surprises:

**Input**

```
     Partner Company
 Firstname  Lastname   
                                        Street. 152 
            12345 City

Tel: 01234 567898
Fax: 01234 567899
Mobile: 0123 567899
```

Now, I've been trying to clean up the string with the preg_replace function ...

**Code**

```
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $lineToOutput);    // remove all blank (empty lines)
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/[\t]/", " ", $lineToOutput); // convert tabs to spaces
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/[ ]{2,}/", " ", $lineToOutput);  // convert multiple spaces to single spaces
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/[\n] /", "\n", $lineToOutput);   // remove spaces at beginning of lines
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/ [\n]/", "\n", $lineToOutput);   // remove spaces at end of lines
```

but failed on removing lines that start and end with spaces.  Any suggestions?

**Output**

```
 Partner Company    <-- unwanted space at beginning of line
Firstname Lastname  <-- unwanted space at end of line (not visible)
 Street. 152        <-- unwanted space at beginning of line
12345 City
Tel: 01234 567898
Fax: 01234 567899
Mobile: 0123 567899
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiline mode, to anchor `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of lines, respectively:

```
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/m", "", $lineToOutput);
```

Using this you can also simplify your first expression:

```
$lineToOutput = preg_replace("/^[\s\t]*[\r\n]+|[\r\n]+\Z/m", "\n", $lineToOutput);    // remove all blank (empty lines)
```

It's not shorter, but I think conceptually easier to understand. The second alternative is to catch a trailing empty line.

Also note that you don't need to write `[\t]`. `\t` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at some nicely parsed data outputted on ym screen

Comment: ah ... look, I found a case where the first expression replacement delivered:  `City\r\n\nTel` (excerpt from result)
It doesn't seem to catch that case.

Comment: @somethis Hm, then go with your initial first expression, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Just the same solution like m.buettner, but a little simpler. 
$lineToOutput = preg_replace('/^\s*|\s*\Z/m', '', $lineToOutput);
```